# Writing a dataframe to CSV where lists are converted to JSON arrays

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, dask

How would a list of strings be outputted as a JSON array when [writing a dataframe to CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)?

E.g. `['foo', 'bar']` should be `["foo", "bar"]`

---

#### Background

I'm copying data from a PostgreSQL DB on AWS RDS to AWS Redshift. As an intermediate step, the data has to be uploaded to AWS S3 in CSV files.

But Redshift doesn't support arrays as a datatype. Arrays need to be converted to a varchar representing a JSON array.

For example, a column of type `character varying(255)[]` on RDS would need a column of type such as `character varying(MAX)` on Redshift, and use [JSON functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html) to interact with the data.

If the data isn't loaded into Redshift as a JSON array, it won't be valid.

```
         json_arrays          | is_valid_json_array
------------------------------+---------------------
 []                           | T
 ["a","b"]                    | T
 ["a",["b",1,["c",2,3,null]]] | T
 {"a":1}                      | F
 a                            | F
 {foo, bar}                   | F
 {"one", "two"}               | F
 [x,y,z]                      | F
 [1,2,]                       | F
 ['x','y','z']                | F
```

The tricky part is that Python represents strings with single quotes internally, so when you write a list of strings to a CSV, that list will use single quotes, which isn't a valid JSON array.

---

An unsuccessful approach was to transform the array when reading the CSV.

```
def convert_pg_array_to_json_array(a):
    """
    Converts a PG array such as '{foo,bar}' to '["foo", "bar"]'
    """
    return json.dumps(a[1:-1].split(','))

# The arrays to convert are in column 20
df = pandas.read_csv(path, converters={20: convert_pg_array_to_json_array})

# Array gets output as "[""foo"", ""bar""]" which is not a valid JSON array
# Desired output is ["foo", "bar"]
df.to_csv(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the approach in the question with these changes when writing the CSV:
Configure an escape character (typically backslash `\`) and disable double quoting.

```
df.to_csv(path, escapechar="\\", doublequote=False)
```

The row in the CSV will look like `[\"foo\", \"bar\"]` which is a valid JSON if you load the data with escaping the backslashes. For a Redshift `COPY FROM` you'll need to add the `ESCAPE` option to the query.